# Issue while sending the file as the response in node API

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to send the file as response in node API.

In my front end I'm getting this error :  **Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse**

In that error I can see the filecontent.

**API Code**

```
        res.download(path,'file.txt',(error) => {
            if(error) {
                error.status = 500
                res.json({
                        status  : error.status,
                        message : error.message,
                     })
            }

        })
```

**Front-End**

```
this.apiservice.downloadattachments('file.txt').subscribe(response => console.log(response))
```

**apiservice**

```
downloadattachments(filePath) : Observable<any> {
  let httpParams = new HttpParams()
  .set('FilePath',filePath)
  return this.http.get<any>(this.baseURL+"/download/attachments",{params : httpParams})
}
```

Comment: You might be trying to parse the content which is not a JSON. Remove that part and you should be good.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46882407/9177552

Comment: add  responseType: any = "arraybuffer" in your angular api, as you can read file as json (in angular default response type is "json")

Comment: @virender nehra, return this.http.get<any>(this.baseURL+"/download/attachments",{params : httpParams,resposneType:arraybuffer}. I'm getting no overload matches this call.Compilation error

Comment: pass arraybuffer  as "arraybuffer"